# Disable the special button function on Microsoft Sculpt mouse

Tags: mouse

I bought the Microsoft Sculpt mouse, with the side button, which is also very sensitive to gestures (up & down).

This is so frustrating to fill a form, grab the mouse to hit the Submit, but the sensor just thought you swipe down the button and goes back to the previous page.

I read [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440059/remap-side-touch-button-on-microsoft-sculpt-comfort-mouse) and tried to have empty action for it. Unfortunately, it is not working. Any other good solution will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to disable the (very annoying) back gesture on my mouse by defining a dummy custom-shortcut.

1. Open the "settings" app
2. Select "Keyboard"
3. Click on "Customize Shortcuts":
   [image]
4. Scroll down and select "Custom shortcuts":
   [image]
5. Choose to add a shortcut writing some dummy command (I used `echo`)
6. Press the "Set shortcut":
   [image]
7. Swipe down the side touch button which should result with:
   [image]
8. Finally click the "Add" button

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate you took the time to post this answer. Until today I didn't had any solution.